# Is Rails a light enough solution for a website with mostly static pages and a few forms?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, sinatra

I'm looking for recommendations on a simpler way to author a small personal website than using Ruby on Rails (with which I would say I have 'intermediate' experience). The site will be mainly static pages built up from chunks (articles, menus, etc) that I would like to be able to author with something like Markdown so that non-techies can write articles.  The site will also need some simple feedback-type forms.  I probably don't need extensive tests.

The site will be pretty minimal in look and I want complete control over the look and feel.  I'm comfortable with Rails, Ruby, Javascript, HTML and CSS.

What I'm wondering is whether I'll be making maintenance (including deployment) and authoring of content for the site more complicated than it needs to be by using Rails.  I've heard a bit about Sinatra that piqued my interest but never used it - would that be less maintenance overhead?

Does the recommendation change if the site requires the user to login?

Comment: It is strange that you are asking, because you have experience with Rails. I don't know it, but I believe a personal site is not loaded enough so that it would matter (in other words, if Rails was not even able to support such a light load, nobody would use it).

Comment: For very basic websites, I use sinatra cause it's the lighter. But it comes with drawbacks: eg no useful helpers etc

Comment: Basile, when I say *personal* I mean that it's a small site that I run myself (but for others).  It's not for a business, so my needs are quite simple.  Also, maybe I didn't make it clear: I'm asking because I don't want to use Rails if there's a lighter solution that allows easy definition of static chunks of HTML (rather than ERB templates for example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've plumped for Sinatra (with Markup templates). This way I can easily build 'static' pages from partials and lob the odd form in too. Thanks for the replies - two people suggested Sinatra and I didn't want to accept one over the other!

Answer (score 5):

Take a look at some of the static website generators listed here:

http://nanoc.stoneship.org/docs/1-introduction/

or here:

https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/static_website_generation

For example, [Jekyll](http://jekyllrb.com/) is gaining in popularity for building static websites that are authored with Markdown. [OctoPress](http://octopress.org/) might even be what you need; it is based on Jekyll for static website generation but it comes with HTML templates, CSS, Javascripts and everything already set up as a blog or CMS.

You mention a need for forms for feedback. You could combine a static website with a simple Rails or Sinatra app; alternatively, it may be easier to add web forms hosted by many of the services that specialize in that.

Comment: Thanks Daniel.  Octopress looks interesting but the forms part would be harder than necessary I think.  I think I'll look at Sinatra.  I'll leave the question open for a bit to see if anyone has any other suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

I did a site in rails, and now one with Sinatra. I can say as a c programmer at heart that rails confuses me with all the 'magic'. Sinatra just seems a better fit for me. It's easy to set up a db with login, etc...

I have found that Sinatra works as advertised, with developers actually working on it, etc. I would deploy on heroku - works great with Sinatra.

But you seem to be describing a Wordpress site - which has control for multiple users, articles, posting, etc. I have built Wordpress and am happy with how easy it all is. The godaddy Wordpress option is really nice. With your own hosted Wordpress you can do a lot. Of course you may have ideas that require some gem, etc.

I think that ruby is better for sites that are not content oriented, but do something original. Maybe you want to do the project to learn Sinatra?

Comment: Yes, I've decided I'll take a look at Sinatra anyway and then I'll be better able to make a decision.